# Progress indicator not showing up

Tags: webview, javafx-2

I have added a progress indicator to my javaFX webview. This has the google page as the loading page by default. The progress indicator till the loading of the google main page works fine. But I want the progress indicator to work or show up when I access further other links in the google search results. The indicator that I have in the code for the controller class only works for the google main page. Please find the code snippet below for your reference.Thanks in advance.

```
public class GoogleController implements Initializable {

@FXML
SplitPane sp;
@FXML
Label welcomeMsg1;
@FXML
Label welcomeMsg2;

@FXML
WebView webview;
@FXML
Label uname;
@FXML
Label status1;
@FXML
ProgressIndicator pi;
String url=null;
/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO

    WebEngine webengine=webview.getEngine();
    WebEngine webengine1=webview.getEngine();
    webengine.load("http://www.google.com");
    pi.progressProperty().bind(webengine.getLoadWorker().progressProperty());
    webengine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
    new ChangeListener<State>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
            if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {

                pi.setVisible(false);
                status1.setText("");

            } else {
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the progress indicator to invisible and never making it visible again.

Instead of calling setVisible(false) in the load worker state change listener, instead, bind the visibility of the progress indicator to its progress amount (directly after you bind the progressProperty).

```
pi.visibleProperty().bind(pi.progressProperty().lessThan(1));
```

This way, the progress property will only show up while loading is in progress, then it will switch to invisible when the page has loaded, then switch back to visible while the next page load is in progress, etc. (from your question this appears to me to be what you want to accomplish).

I do find that having the progress indicator pop in and out of visibility is a bit annoying, so you may want to rethink your design and make the progress bar persistent anyway (or at least makes it's styling unobtrusive or perform fade in and fade out animations for it).

Comment: Thank you @jewelsea,this way,it's working.But I want to also show texts like "Page is loading" while it's getting loaded and fade out when it's completed.

Comment: @Himanshu, JavaFX can do those kind of things by using a Label and applying [FadeTransitions](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/FadeTransition.html), however they aren't really the same as the original question, so try implementing them yourself and create new questions (not comments) when you need to.

Comment: Another way to show/hide the progress bar "automatically" when loading a url is performing the following bind: `pi.visibleProperty().bind(webengine.getLoadWorker().runningProperty());`

Comment: @jewelsea,sure i will...thannks!